# Attempt to set a plist value error on registering Dictionary of Ints with NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, foundation

I have the following snippet of code that is causing my app to crash:

```
let defaults = [1 : 0]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["highScores":defaults])
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object {
1 = 0;
} for key highScores'
```

I don't get it though. Why wouldn't [1 : 0] be a plist? It is made up of Ints stored in a Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from Apple docs:

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to
>   be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the
>   collections are not property-list objects

Your code should work by substituting `let defaults = ["1" : 0]` for your first assignment.